# Conflict between Delphi and SQL server

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, delphi-xe

I have a Query that works in SQL Server as well but when i save it in ado query in delphi it doesn't work and stops with this error :

```
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'
```

But the below code is correct and has not any error . i was tested it in sql server .
The below code is not Regular because i copy and past it from delphi .

My Query :

```
create function GetTedad(@pfcode INT, @pdcode INT) returns int
as begin declare @Tedad int;
select @Tedad= sum(t2.tedade_avalie) from Tbl_avalie_salon t2 where t2.FCode = @pfcode and t2.DCode = @pdcode
return (@Tedad); end;
GO
create function getSumBSen2(@pfcode INT, @pdcode INT, @pSen INT) returns int
as begin declare @r int;
select @r= sum(t2.t_shab + t2.t_rooz) from tbl_talafat_dan t2 where t2.FCode = @pfcode and t2.DCode = @pdcode and t2.sen <= @pSen;
return (@r); end;
GO
select t1.sen, sum(t1.d_rooz) as d1, sum(t1.d_shab) as d2, sum(t1.d_rooz + t1.d_shab) as d_sum,
Round((sum((1000*(t1.d_rooz+t1.d_shab)+0.01)/((dbo.GetTedad(81, 1))-(dbo.getSumBSen2(81, 1, t1.sen))))),1) as Saraneh
from tbl_talafat_dan t1 where t1.FCode =81 and t1.DCode = 1 group by t1.sen;
```

Comment: Try search and replace all lines with only GO on the line with a semi-colon. I have a hunch this might work, but never taken the time to test it properly.

Comment: @CraigYoung - That will not work. `create function` has to be in a batch of it's own.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson thanks, I didn't know whether semi-colon would be treated as a batch separator... I guess not. :(  However, I have found a link to another option seriously worth considering: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/07/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-_2D00_-the-easy-way.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The [`GO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) keyword is not a SQL Server statement

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code
>   editor.

You must remove this statement from your Delphi Code in order to execute your Sql sentence. check this question for an example [`How to run a database script file from Delphi?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985486/how-to-run-a-database-script-file-from-delphi)

Comment: So how can i run my functions ,,,, if i dont use GO the code doesn't works at all . you mean i cant use 2 functions in one query ?

Comment: That depends of the component which you are using. Check the sample posted in the question link.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do multiple statements in a Delphi query.
Put each block before each `go` in its own query and run them in sequence.

Then it should work.
Do not put the `go` statement in the Delphi query, it does `go` implicitly.

Comment: thank you but i dont know what should i do for this ---> Put each block before each go in its own query and run them in sequence.

Comment: @user980115 Create 3 queries with and run them one after another.

Comment: its one query cant be 3 . i need to run functions together .

Answer (score 1):

What you are executing is a script where each individual statement is separated with a `GO`statement.

- `SSMS` knows how to interprete these statements and execute them one at the time.
- `ADO` does not know how to interprete these statements.

You could either

- parse the statement yourself and execute each individual statement with a `TADOQuery`.
- place each statement in a `TADOQuery` object of its own.

From [GO(Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code
>   editor.
>
> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send
>   the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL
>   Server. The current batch of statements is composed of all statements
>   entered since the last GO, or since the start of the ad hoc session or
>   script if this is the first GO.